# Lightbox2 width automatically sets

Tags: javascript, lightbox2

I'm having problems with resizing, if i for example look at a picture that's 800px in width, and then i get a picture with 200px width, then all other pictures gets the same width until i get a picture with a width of 100px then they go down to that resolution. It all goes away when i refresh the page but starts over again. The same problem occurs in all browsers(ie,chrome,firefox and safari)

Suspecting a caching problem but can't really find where that problem might be

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also had this problem and it seems Bootstrap caused the problem here try to add this css-line

> ```
> .lb-image{   max-width: inherit; }
> ```

Comment: I had the same problem using Lightbox2 with Shopify's Kickstand theme. I added this to the lightbox CSS file and it fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: did you add this to the lightbox.css or bootstrap.css